# Cemetery Mapping System using ArcGis

Tags: mapping, gis, arcgis

I'm currently working on my thesis, I need help on how to make a cemetery mapping system using arcgis, im not very familiar with gis but im willing to learn so i can pass. If you know any tutorials related to the topic or if you've done something like this in the past, feel free to help! thank you

Comment: People doing cemetery mapping using ArcGIS usually ask their questions at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing it from scratch? In ArcGIS you can upload shapefiles that you download from the internet. You can also create your own shapefiles.

I guess some tutorials like this might be helpful:
1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUnUrTzP2dw
2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrxWbZ5uHXQ

ArcGis is awesome, though a bit overwhelming at first. Have fun!